# Shopware : How to set a free gift to customer based on number of orders?

Tags: plugins, orders, shopware

I want to implement new functionality for customers to give label and a free gift on number of orders.

See below.

```
Order No     Label         Gift

Order #1   – “Magnet”     - Spoon
Order #2   – “Löffel”     - Woods Table
Order #3   – “Extra Glas” - Chair
Order #4   – “Korbmarke”  - Table
Order #5   – “Schneidebrett” - Xyz
Order #10  – “Beutel”      - ABC
```

I have already purchased one plugin but it will provide functionality to add a free gift to customer if order amount is Greater Or Less then X amount then you will get a free gift.

https://store.shopware.com/en/dvsn891149791221/automatically-add-premium-items/gifts-to-shopping-cart.html

Can anyone help me how can I setup free gift on number of orders rather than price?
Is there any ready made plugin available for this functionality?

Any help would be appreciated...!

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Hi,

i could not find any existing plugin in the store that matches your criteria. So you have to implement this functionality on your own.